# Windows Gadget - Text on transparent background

Tags: javascript, windows, windows-desktop-gadgets

[image]

You see my problem on those text.

I need to know, can I have g:text or html text on a transparent background without the pink effect like picture.

Thanks

This is my code:

```
<g:background id="background" src="background.png" >
    <br><br><br>
     <g:text value="Hello"  color="black" >Hello data Center Testing</g:text>
        <span id="gadgetContent">
        Hello, World!
    </span>

</g:background>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must use g:text to display text without the magenta artifact. HTML text definitely doesn't work.

However, when developing my gadget I found the only way to avoid the magenta was to dynamically add the text objects to the g:background element.

`background.addTextObject` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa359355(v=vs.85).aspx

You can also download my gadget, and extract the source (it's unobfuscated).
http://adamncasey.co.uk/gadget.php

However for the sake of this answer being complete, I attach an `onload` event, and then I add all of my text objects to the `g:background` (the `g:background` is defined in HTML).

```
function onloadevent()
{
     document.getElementById("background").addTextObject("Hello data centre testing", "Calibri", 20, "black", 25, 25);
}
window.attachEvent("onload", onloadevent);
```

Should do the trick